# Android Studio/Java: error: incomparable types: Switch and boolean

Tags: java, android

i'm kinda new to Android Studio, and Java in general...
Quick recap of my project: 
Bluetooth controlled car, from smartphone til arduino. Thats kinda it.

My code is a mix of different codes + my own. But i got the following error, when trying to make a switch that (right now turns a LED on and off) will start and stop the car.

> error: incomparable types: Switch and boolean

Maybe i just dont understand if statements. This is the section where the error occurred:

```
 Switch on_off_switch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.on_off_switch);
    on_off_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.v("Switch State=", ""+isChecked);
        }

    });

    if (on_off_switch == true) {
        command = "1";
        try
        {
            outputStream.write(command.getBytes()); //transmits the value of command to the bluetooth module
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Maybe the problems comes from somewhere else in the code, so here is it all:

```
package com.example.btcar2;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final String DEVICE_ADDRESS = "00:12:12:24:06:48"; //MAC Address of Bluetooth Module
    private final UUID PORT_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    private BluetoothDevice device;
    private BluetoothSocket socket;
    private OutputStream outputStream;

    Button  bluetooth_connect_btn;

    String command; //string variable that will store value to be transmitted to the bluetooth module

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Switch on_off_switch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.on_off_switch);
        on_off_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.v("Switch State=", ""+isChecked);
            }

        });

        if (on_off_switch == true) {
            command = "1";
            try
            {
                outputStream.write(command.getBytes()); //transmits the value of command to the bluetooth module
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        bluetooth_connect_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bluetooth_connect_btn);

        //Button that connects the device to the bluetooth module when pressed
        bluetooth_connect_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(BTint())
                {
                    BTconnect();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    //Initializes bluetooth module
    public boolean BTint()
    {
        boolean found = false;

        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if(bluetoothAdapter == null) //Checks if the device supports bluetooth
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device doesn't support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) //Checks if bluetooth is enabled. If not, the program will ask permission from the user to enable it
        {
            Intent enableAdapter = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableAdapter,0);

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Set<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if(bondedDevices.isEmpty()) //Checks for paired bluetooth devices
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please pair the device first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
        {
            for(BluetoothDevice iterator : bondedDevices)
            {
                if(iterator.getAddress().equals(DEVICE_ADDRESS))
                {
                    device = iterator;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return found;
    }

    public boolean BTconnect()
    {
        boolean connected = true;

        try
        {
            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(PORT_UUID); //Creates a socket to handle the outgoing connection
            socket.connect();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Connection to bluetooth device successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            connected = false;
        }

        if(connected)
        {
            try
            {
                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream(); //gets the output stream of the socket
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return connected;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
    }

}
```

Sorry if my question is not clear. It's also my first time asking a question on stackoverflow. Please just write if you have a question that might help my situation :) Thank you

Comment: You're writing `on_off_switch == true` while `on_off_switch` is of type `Switch` and you're trying to compare it to a `boolean`. What is it that you meant to check by writing that statement?

Comment: tbh, i dont know what a boolean is.. sorry. 

But my idea is to make it transmit a value to the other bt device, when the switch is turned on. Maybe this is not the right way to do it

Comment: A boolean is a value that can be either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error: incomparable types: Switch and boolean

This tells you that you are attempting to compare two values which cannot be compared. In this case, you are trying to compare a `Switch` which represents a UI element to a `boolean` which is a built-in type which can only have the values `true` and `false.

Like I said, a `Switch` is a UI element. It can be either "on" or "off" This state is stored in the `Switch` object and we need to figure out how to access it. We can look at [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch) to find the right method to do so. Scroll down to the section labeled "Public methods" and scan the method names to find something that sounds like it might do the job. There doesn't seem to be anything obvious about getting the state of the `Switch`, so we have to look a little deeper. Scroll down to the "Inherited methods" section and expand the "CompoundButton" section. As we scroll down, we see that there is an `isChecked()` method.

So let's try it:

```
if (on_off_switch.isChecked())
```

Note that you do not need to use `== true`. The value of a comparison is a boolean value (either `true` or `false`), but `isChecked()` already returns a boolean value, so there is no need for the extra typing.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you're trying to compare a `Switch` object with a `boolean` value, and this is not allowed.  
The way to get the state of the `Switch` is by `isChecked()` method:

```
if (on_off_switch.isChecked() == true)
```

or simply:

```
if (on_off_switch.isChecked())
```